# Eloquent puts selectRaw bindings in where clause

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

For some reason, Eloquent puts bindings used in selectRaw to all where clauses.

```
DB::query()
            ->selectRaw(
                "tr.user_id,
                SUM(
                    CASE WHEN tr.updated_at >= :date
                ) as inc_today,
                ",
                [
                    ':date' => 'test'
                ]
            )
            ->from('transactions as tr')
            ->where('tr.type', '=', 'type1')
            ->where('tr.status', '=', 'success')
            ->groupBy(['tr.user_id'])
            ->orderBy('income', $orderBy)
            ->paginate(
                perPage: $perPage,
                page: $page
            );
```

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from (select tr.user_id,\n                SUM(\n                    CASE WHEN tr.updated_at >= :date\n                ) as inc_today,\n                 from `transactions` as `tr` where `tr`.`type` = test and `tr`.`status` = type1 group by `tr`.`user_id`) as `aggregate_table`)

It puts test to `tr.type` instead of putting it to selectRaw

I expect that Eloquent will put my binding for selectRaw directly to selectRaw and not to where clauses

Comment: `mixed named and positional parameters` - Laravel by default uses `?` for the placeholders in the `where` clauses. So your prepared query really looks like `select tr.user_id, SUM(  CASE WHEN tr.updated_at >= :date  ) as inc_today,  from transactions as tr where tr.type = ? and tr.status = ? group by tr.user_id) as aggregate_table)`, and the database doesn't like mixing the uses. Use the question mark instead of the named parameter for your `selectRaw` clause

Comment: @aynber Please add it as an answer. It really helped me. I didn't know that named bindings will not work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error refers to `mixed named and positional parameters` - Laravel by default uses `?` for the placeholders in the where clauses. So your prepared query really looks like

```
 select count(*) as aggregate from 
     (select tr.user_id,
       SUM(  CASE WHEN tr.updated_at >= :date ) as inc_today,
 from transactions as tr 
 where tr.type = ? and tr.status = ? group by tr.user_id) as aggregate_table
```

The database doesn't like mixing the uses. Use the question mark instead of the named parameter for your selectRaw clause

```
DB::query()
        ->selectRaw(
            "tr.user_id,
            SUM(
                CASE WHEN tr.updated_at >= ?
            ) as inc_today
            ",
            [
                'test'
            ]
        )
        ->from('transactions as tr')
        ->where('tr.type', '=', 'type1')
        ->where('tr.status', '=', 'success')
        ->groupBy(['tr.user_id'])
        ->orderBy('income', $orderBy)
        ->paginate(
            perPage: $perPage,
            page: $page
        );
```

I'd also suggest removing that trailing comma in your `selectRaw` clause.